# JQuery not running in PHP Document

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue getting some JQuery to run, i have a PHP file name index.php which is running on my server hosted by a hosting company.

in the script tag i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Juan</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="igotswag.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function)
    {
        $("jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone");
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

The part in the script tag is a test because i could even get it to read from my scripts.js file where i have used code from code academy for a pull down div.

However even the simple Hello everyone isn't working

**The HTML:**

```
<!-- Header Area -->
<table style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40%; text-align: left;"><img src="Images/TEAMS_Logo.png"></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;" class="custom-header">TEAMS Wiki</td>
        <td style="width: 40%;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="panel">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Now you see me!</p>
</div>
<p class="slide">
    <div class="pull-me">Slide Up/Down</div>
</p>
<!-- End Header Area -->




<!-- Main Body Area -->

<div class="mainContainer" align="center">
    <div class="noteSelectionBoxContainer">
        <div class="noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top1">
            <div class="vertical-align-content">
                <div class="noSelect"><div class="noteboxText">GENERAL NOTES</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top2">
            <div class="vertical-align-content">
                <div class="noSelect"><div class="noteboxText">TEMPLATE NOTES</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="noteSelectionBox hvr-bounce-to-top3">
            <div class="vertical-align-content">
                <div class="noSelect"><div class="noteboxText">REPLACE VARIABLES</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="jquerytest"></div>

<!-- End Main Body Area -->


<!-- Footer Area -->

<!-- End Footer Area -->

</body>
</html>
```

**The CSS:**

```
/* Pull down menu */


.pull-me
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.panel 
{
    background: #ffffbd;
  background-size:90% 90%;
  height:300px;
    display:none;
  font-family:garamond,times-new-roman,serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel p
{
    text-align:center;
}
.slide 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:solid 2px #A4A4A4;
  text-align: center;
}
.pull-me 
{
  text-align: center;
    display:block;
  position:relative;
  right:-25px;
  width:150px;
  height:25px;
    font-family:"customFontTwo",sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  background:#A4A4A4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.pull-me p 
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**The JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow')
    });
});
```

So basically nothing JS/Jquery related is working and im not sure why.

If you have an account on Code Acedemy its [this](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-GfjC6/2/3?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1) im trying to achieve.

So in short, both using Jquery in script tag isnt working AND linking from another file doesnt seem to be working either

Comment: To access id you need to prepend "#". $("#jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone");

Comment: The first little problem I see is this $("jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone"); should be $("#jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone"); Note the "#" to define you are looking for an ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, the first javascript file that you are including is `scripts.js`, that have a `$(document)....`. When the browser engine reads `$` browser tell you that is not a function (see your console errors before ask!!!)

So, if you move jQuery inclusion before scripts.js inclusion, it works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Juan</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="igotswag.css" type="text/css">
```

The other problem is that `jquerytest` is not an element in your html. So you need to make some changes:

```
 $("#jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone");
 ---^ // select by id with #
```

And include in your html:

```
 <div id="jquerytest"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies for asking, i wasnt too sure where to find my logs for these errors, i will contact my host and fin out where to find them. Thank you for the answer will vote as answer once i can, this has worked!

Comment: The errors on the console is in your browser. Your hosting provider can't help you. You must access to developer tools on your browser (F12 on chrome / IE and Shift+F2 on Firefox), go to Console tab and when you run the script you'll see all errors. Glad to help you, i will wait for the correct check :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all $ symbols with jQuery, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function)
{
    jQuery("jquerytest").html("Hello Everyone");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the "#"